# How to write browser output to log file using PHP?

Tags: php, io, cron

I have the script is which runned by Cron jobs. So, while it runs, I can't see what output of the task is. (errors and so on.) 
So I need to write browser output to log file using PHP. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this script for error logs:

```
// Destinations
define("ADMIN_EMAIL", "nobody@stanford.edu");
define("LOG_FILE", "/my/home/errors.log");
 
// Destination types
define("DEST_EMAIL", "1");
define("DEST_LOGFILE", "3");
 
/**
  * my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
  *
  * Author(s): thanosb, ddonahue
  * Date: May 11, 2008
  * 
  * custom error handler
  *
  * Parameters:
  *  $errno:   Error level
  *  $errstr:  Error message
  *  $errfile: File in which the error was raised
  *  $errline: Line at which the error occurred
  */
 
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{  
  switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
      // Send an e-mail to the administrator
      error_log("Error: $errstr \n Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile \n", DEST_EMAIL, ADMIN_EMAIL);
 
      // Write the error to our log file
      error_log("Error: $errstr \n Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
 
    case E_USER_WARNING:
      // Write the error to our log file
      error_log("Warning: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
 
    case E_USER_NOTICE:
      // Write the error to our log file
      error_log("Notice: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
 
    default:
      // Write the error to our log file
      error_log("Unknown error [#$errno]: $errstr \n in $errfile on line $errline \n", DEST_LOGFILE, LOG_FILE);
      break;
  }
 
  // Don't execute PHP's internal error handler
  return TRUE;
}
 
 
// Use set_error_handler() to tell PHP to use our method
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("my_error_handler");
```

It gives full control over what actions to take when an error is raised. 
*Taken directly from  [Web Services Wiki of Stanford University](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_perform_error_handling_in_PHP)*

Answer (score 5):

You can use [output buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)  to write browser output to a log file,

Example:

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit';
echo 'Cras in dolor fringilla est fermentum porttito';
echo 'bla bla bla...';
echo 'bla bla bla...';

file_put_contents('/path/to/log.txt',ob_get_contents());
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The I prefer to do is the output redirection using bash features:

```
php myscript.php > logfile.log
```

But you need to know that PHP outputs errors to `stderr`. So, you need to redirect `stderr` too. Everything is described here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/ . Some examples according to this page:

```
php myscript.php &>file
```

or

```
php myscript.php > file-name 2>&1
```

Also, you cannot use [`output control functions`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) like `ob_start()` and friends alone, because some fatal error can abort output buffering. So, if you prefer PHP-only way, you need to define:

1. Output buffering
2. Error handler (or you can fetch errors using output buffering)
3. Shutdown function - to fetch fatal errors

P.S. Usually, cron job`s output is written to crontab`s log

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the output of the php script in the cron instruction using the [file redirection](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/iodirection.html) "php yourfile.php > logfile.log" or you can use php's [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save to a file anywhere you would have called print.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen("log.txt", "a");
fwrite ($file, $some_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly create javascript code in html page

```js
var UI_LOG_ENABLED_FOR = 'ALL';

  var userTokensLog = UI_LOG_ENABLED_FOR.split(',');

  var logTextServer = [];
  if( UI_LOG_ENABLED_FOR =='ALL' )
  {
var writeLogIntoFile = function(type,text1,text2,text3){
  logTextServer.push([new Date(),type,text1,text2,text3]);
}
// define a new console
var console=(function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text1,text2=null,text3=null){
            oldCons.log(text1,text2,text3);
        
            writeLogIntoFile('log',text1,text2,text3);
   
        },
        info: function (text1,text2=null,text3=null) {
            oldCons.info(text1,text2,text3);
            writeLogIntoFile('info',text1,text2,text3);
     
        },
        warn: function (text1,text2=null,text3=null) {
            oldCons.warn(text1,text2,text3);
            writeLogIntoFile('warn',text1,text2,text3);


        },
        table: function (text1,text2=null,text3=null) {
            oldCons.warn(text1,text2,text3);
            writeLogIntoFile('warn',text1,text2,text3);


        },
        error: function (text1,text2=null,text3=null) {
            oldCons.error(text1,text2,text3);
            writeLogIntoFile('error',text1,text2,text3);
       
        }
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console;
//Amol Patil
setInterval(function(){
  try{
  
    if(logTextServer.length >0){

        $.post('/api/v1/store-ui-log', {username:'xyz-user',log_data:logTextServer}, function(response){ 
     
        });
   
    }
  logTextServer = [];
  }catch(err){
     console.error(err);
  }
},5000);
  }
```

then call PHP API
PHP CODE :

```html
    public function createLog(Request $request)
    {
      
        $path = storage_path() . '/ui_logs';
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $path = storage_path() . '/ui_logs/Log_'.date('Y-m-d');
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }
        $path = $path.'/'.$request->username.'.txt';
        $myfile = fopen($path, "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
            foreach($request->get('log_data') as $log){
                fwrite($myfile, json_encode($log).PHP_EOL);

            }
            fclose($myfile);
        
        return "done";
    }
```